# Rails dumping a file as the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im from a PHP background so I know this is possible. I'm not sure how to do it in rails though.

Basically instead of outputting text I'd like to output a binary stream (basically a file) and throw in a `Content-Type: audio/mpeg` as well as a `Content-Disposition` header so the browser accepts it as a download

I also have this in a variable that I'd like to print as the binary stream without writing the file to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data).

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a stream I have in a variable? I don't want to write it to disk before sending it and deleting it off after

Comment: In that case you have to use [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data).